# How To Handle CallBack from php web application in inAppBroser.create() in ionic 4

Tags: php, ionic-framework, inappbrowser

Note: Long explanation, please read till end it was necessary to explain current working and problem

I have an existing web application, I am trying to create an IONIC 4 application In which under `initializeApp()` in `app.component.ts` I open my web app in `InAppBroser`.

It works fine, When I open my Ionic android app, it open the web app URL and redirect me to Login page.

Now I want to bypass the login functionality.
So in order to that,  from `InAppBroser.create()` method I am passing my username and password as a URL parameter and it works good.

Now problem comes when I change my username and password.

**What implementation i want to do.**

At the time of opening Ionic application, it will check the username and password in mobile system parameter, if it does not find it, then it will open a custom IONIC login page where user will enter credentials and pres login button.

On login action of IONIC it will save the credentials in mobile system parameter and refresh the page.

Now it will get credentials from system parameters and it will pass that with URL while calling `InAppBrowser.create();`

Now problem comes, when credentials are wrong.
In Web app if login action page gets wrong credentials then it redirect to `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`

Now how I will handle this `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` in ionic app?

Because what is currently happening in case of wrong credentials

- Ionic app call web app login from InAppBroser.create().
- Web App login redirect again to Ionic
- Ionic again call to Web app login from
- InAppBroser.create(). Web app login again redirect to Ionic
- Ionic again call to Web app login from
- and so on, it run in a loop

**What is needed:**

- When User give wrong credentials.
- web app will give call back to Ionic app.
- now Ionic app will sense the call back from web application and will
  open Custom IONIC login page
- Where user will insert his credentials and it should save it in
  mobile system parameter.

**How can I set and get the system parameter in Ionic?**

**How will I handle the call back from PHP Login Action?**

Ionic code

[image]

PHP login action code

[image]